# Elasticsearch ignore borders in Intersect query

Tags: elasticsearch, shapes, spatial-index

So I query against preindexed shapes. Some shapes in the value index have the exact same border as in the shape index (as they are subshapes from them). When I query with one of those shapes I always get all values which only share the same boarder but otherwise have no intersection. Is there any way of excluding these?

```
GET value/Value
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "geo_shape": {
          "locationArea": {
            "indexed_shape": {
              "id": "AShape1",
              "type": "Shapes"
            }
          },
          "_name": null
        }
      },
      {
        "geo_shape": {
          "locationArea": {
            "indexed_shape": {
              "id": "AShape2",
              "type": "Shapes"
            }
          },
          "_name": null
        }
      },
      {
        "geo_shape": {
          "locationArea": {
            "indexed_shape": {
              "id": "AShape3",
              "type": "Shapes"
            }
          },
          "_name": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the query you are running?

Comment: Sure. Its a pretty basic shape query

Comment: did you try with `"relation": "contains"`?

Comment: Contains/Within means that either shape has to be fully within the other. Which is not always the case here. It would prevent the problem for some of the shapes but open another for the others..

Comment: oh right i reread your question, i had formed the wrong notion that you wanted a contains kind of a thing.
You're right about the problem. I have never tried it, but perhaps you could try changing the precision to centimeters or something finer.

see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html

Comment: The points touch each other they are essentially the same borders in some part. So the positive is actually correct but its just a touch not a real overlap.